# How to calculate electrostatic potential energy of two hydrogenic charges?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electrostatics, charge, potential-energy

To my understanding, if I want to calculate the energy of two well-separated hydrogen atoms, then this entails evaluating the Coulomb interaction energy. If the charges $a$ belonging to hydrogen atom $A$ and the charges $b$ to atom $B$ would be classical point charges, then the energy would be (in atomic units):

$$ H' = \sum_{a \in A} \sum_{b \in B} \frac{q_A q_B}{r_{ab}}  $$

My understanding is that I could treat this interaction as a perturbation operator, and for continuous charge densities I would get, in first order, an integral over the full space:

$$ H'^{(1)} = \int \int_V d\pmb{r} d\pmb{r}' \frac{\rho_A(\pmb{r}) \rho_B(\pmb{r}')}{\left| \pmb{r} - \pmb{r}' \right|} $$

To evaluate this integral, I should use the unperturbed density:

$$ \rho(\pmb{r}) = \delta(\pmb{r}_0) - \frac{\exp(-2 r)}{\pi} $$

Now if I assume nucleus $A$ is at $\pmb{r}_0 = (0,0,0)$ and nucleus $B$ is at $\pmb{r}'_0 = (0,0,d)$, then the integral to evaluate should be:

$$ H'^{(1)} = \int_V dx\, dy\, dz\, dx'\, dy'\, dz'\, \frac{\left(\delta({0,0,0}) - \frac{\exp(-2 \sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2})}{\pi}\right) \left(\delta(0,0,d) - \frac{\exp(-2 \sqrt{x'^2+y'^2+(z'-d)^2}}{\pi}\right) }{\sqrt{(x-x')^2+(y-y')^2+(z-z'-d)^2}}$$

I can't evaluate this integral by hand (probably my notation is all over the place too, at this point), but I'd expect that I can put it into Mathematica at least. However, when I do that it tells me that this integral is divergent.

Is this a true physical result, that the electrostatic interaction of two hydrogen atoms is undefined? Or am I misunderstanding some quantities that I am expected to use here? How would I calculate this energy?

---

**Edit**

Based on a discussion in the comments, I've found that the integral I'm looking for is a generalization of an exercise found in Griffith's QM book.

In the book, the two charges are distributed around the same origin (it is said to model the two electrons of the helium atom), and the integral is evaluated in spherical coordinates. The main idea is to realize that if the zenith axis is along one of the charge coordinates, then the distance only depends on the azimuthal angle of the other charge, so the integral to solve is

$$ \int \int  \frac{\exp(-2r) \exp(-2r')}{\sqrt{r^2+r'^2-2rr' \cos \theta}} d^3\pmb{r} d^3\pmb{r'} $$

Apparently this integral is not very hard to evaluate (not straightforward, but definitely manageable with a pen and a paper).

What I am looking for is a generalization of this quantity: how do I evaluate this integral if the two charges are not centered around the same origin? The way I see this is that two things need to be changed about the integral

1. The distance between two points must be the full distance between two spherical points, which I believe is given in this [beautiful answer.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/833002/distance-between-two-points-in-spherical-coordinates)
2. The radial coordinate of one of the particles (eg. the one belonging to atom B) must be displaced by the distance $d$.

I am not entirely sure about the second point, but if that is right, then the integral would be

$$ \int \int  \frac{\exp(-2r) \exp(-2(r'-d))}{\sqrt{r^2+(r'-d)^2-2r(r'-d) \left[ \sin\theta\sin\theta' \cos \phi-\phi' + \cos \theta \cos \theta' \right] }  } d^3\pmb{r} d^3\pmb{r'} $$

Is my understanding about setting up this integral correct? And if yes, do I have a chance to evaluate it analytically?

Comment: I think the integral is to be taken over the whole free space - I should have indicated it somewhere. Adding a small subscript for it now.

Comment: Griffiths has an example of this type integral in an example on helium atom.  Are you sure about the $\delta$ function?

Comment: I've found the exercise in Griffiths, thank you, it gives me some idea on how to proceed (problem 5.11 in 2nd ed. of the quantum mechanics book). I am not sure about the $\delta$ but I do assume that I need to account for the nuclei to get the correct energy. I'll try to spend a few more days with the help of Griffith now, and will see.

Comment: I've edited the question to reflect on the recipe of Griffith.